# Realize a group as a subset of a metric space

Tags: group-theory, geometry

I have a question about the definition of "*realize*". I read the following definition:

> A group $G$ is said to be *realized* as a subset $Y \subseteq X$ of a
>   metric space $X$ if the isometry group of $Y$ is isomorphic to $G$.

Is this definition correct like this? Can someone give an application/example of this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to define exactly, but the definition that you've stated doesn't make much sense to me.  What is $Y$?  And how is being a subset of $X$ related to being isomorphic with the isometry group of $X$?

Comment: @JimBelk fixed. X is just some metric space. I meant the isometry group of Y.

Comment: The reason I am curious about this is because of this http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869399981899 and because I read the following: The solvable Lie group $\text{Sol}_{2n-1} = \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \ltimes \mathbb{R}^{n}$ can be realized as a horosphere in a product of hyperbolic planes.

Comment: The definition makes more sense, but what do you mean when you say that you have a question about _the_ definition of "realize"?  "Realize" isn't a mathematical term that's defined precisely -- it's just a verb that comes up in mathematical statements.  In the same way that there isn't a definition of "show", "suppose", or "rewrite", there's not a definition of "realize".

Comment: The definition of "realize" in the paper you link to is confined to that paper.  It is not used in other contexts.

Comment: @JimBelk well, yes exactly that what I was curious about. I thought realize has some definition (because of the albertson article), that confused me. So if it is just confined to this paper, then that clears things up :)

Comment: You might want to start a new question about the meaning of the sentence about $\mathrm{Sol}_{2n-1}$.  The author of the sentence is probably just using "realize" in place of some more precise term, and depending on the reader to understand the meaning of the sentence from context.